# Cannot connect to own websocket server when on secured domain

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, laravel-websockets

I deployed a standalone WebSocket server in google cloud.  Following the [laravel-websockets](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets) configuration, I can connect to my server when I go to `<ip address>/laravel-websockets`.

[image]

I installed an SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt then I configured the `.env` file to point to my certs and key files:

`LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem`
`LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem`

Then I open the WebSockets dashboard, using the domain name instead of the IP `mydomain.com/laravel-websockets`.  I restarted apache `sudo systemctl restart apache2` and run `php artisan WebSockets:serve`.  Then I tried connecting but failed.

[image]

The console shows:

> WebSocket connection to
> 'wss://mydomain.com:6001/app/mypusherkey?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false'
> failed

Please advise as I need this to work soon.  Thank you.

Comment: Does google by some chance have a sort of request origin protection to worry about?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693376/websocket-connection-on-wss-failed

Answer (score 0):

This might be a dumb question, but are you sure if the port 6001 isn't blocked by a firewall?

Comment: I already added 6001 in the firewall and even allow 6001 using ufw... i gave up and just use DigitalOcean.  I still don't know why it's so hard to make this work in GCP.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in documentation here: https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/blob/master/docs/basic-usage/ssl.md and from you mentioning the `.env` file, I am afraid you have a simple misconfiguration.

Variables that are configured to the PHP `$_ENV` or to be retrieved with `getenv()` are configured via php.ini file. If you use contenerized environment what does suggest to me the fact, that you are straightforward mentioning `.env` file, [here on shiphp](https://www.shiphp.com/blog/env-php-docker) is a decent article about some solutions to achieve custom env vars. I would first try one of two mentioned there solutions:

#### Mix the `--env-file` to the docker command

[shiphp](https://www.shiphp.com/blog/env-php-docker) suggests command

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app -w /app --env-file .env php:cli php index.php
```

and this is pretty close to what you need to run PHP (here `php:cli` image) with your custom `.env` file as variables configuration

#### Docker ENV variables

This is less straightforward but more managable. Also [shiphp](https://www.shiphp.com/blog/env-php-docker) suggests that you can create your own image:

```
FROM php:cli
ENV LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT=...
ENV LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK=...
```

---

All suggestions are related to docker or configuration, because unfortunately you left very little information for PHP developer to help you here. Imo your socket is not up, or is up but with default configuration, what would be non-ssl. Please try to first determine if the socket is up, before trying to debug connection from other application to it. You can connect from HTTP website to both WS and WSS. Bare in mind connecting from HTTPS is possible only to WSS.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @yergo, sounds like you have a misconfiguration, you can hit it via IP but not domain, check your env inside the docker container. "docker -exec -it  echo $<ENV_VAR>".
If response is empty then your env settinhs are not applied to the container.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).